# "if elif" statement dependent on input won't run after placing my input

Tags: python-3.x

My problem is the script ends immediately after I enter an input.
[image]

```
def add(var1, var2):
    print(var1 + var2)
def times(var1, var2):
    print(var1*var2)

x = input("press 1 to add, press 2 to multiply: ")

if x == 1:
    print("what two number do you want to add?")
    a = input("input first number: ")
    b = input("input second number: ")
    add(a, b)
elif x == 2:
    print("what two number do you want to multiply?")
    a = input("input first number: ")
    b = input("input second number: ")
    times(a, b)
```

I want the script to run the if-elif statement which is dependent on the entered input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` function returns a string. You should therefore either compare its returning value to a string instead of an integer:

```
if x == '1':
...
if x == '2':
```

or convert the returning value to an integer first:

```
x = int(input("press 1 to add, press 2 to multiply: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

The input will be a string not a number, and 2 != '2'. You need to convert the input to an integer before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` will return `str`, you need to convert it to `int` before calculating.

```
x = input("press 1 to add, press 2 to multiply: ")
```